# Windows Form App - MVP Design Pattern best practice

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvp

I just have started to use MVP design pattern on Windows Form Application.
I have structured my code into 3 folders (Model, View, Presenter), and I have managed to build my UI so far.

What I'm trying to do now is to add some new classes, which will help me to do some operations (recording input sound, work with xlsx files, etc...). I don't know where to put these classes. I should think to implement them using MVP? Or I should make another folder, Common for eg., and I should put there all additional classes that I use?

Is this a good practice?

Comment: I would organise your classes by feature not by type. Having a folder for each type soon gets messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the previous answer, i guess you should have a service package which contain your logic something like

- Project

  - Model

    - your model
  - View

    - MainView
  - Presenter

    - Core

      - IApplicationController
      - IPresenter
      - IView
    - PresenterMainView

      - IMainView
      - IMainViewPresenter
      - MainViewPresenter
  - services

    - Input
    - Excel
    - ...

Answer (score 0):

These classes sound like they could be considered 'Services'. Why not create a Services folder and add them there?